# can not retrieve row marked dirty by(jqGrid("setCell", rowId ,'area' ,'', "dirty-cell" ) ( using getChangedCells('dirty');

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jsp, jquery

I use this code below, to mark a specific column 'area' as dirty.

```
    $("#list4").jqGrid("setCell", rowId ,'area' ,'', "dirty-cell" );
```

and i want to retrieve this row marked as dirty using code below:

```
var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');
```

I am not able to retrieve this modified row using getChangedCells('dirty');

however if i use hard coded value like below

```
$("#list4").jqGrid("setCell", rowId ,'area' ,'200', "dirty-cell" );
```

i can see this changed value in jqGrid but i am still not able to retrieve this row using

```
getChangedCells('dirty');
```

Any help would be highly appreciable

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//With the help i got from Oleg, it works like i wanted.. 

    var $grid = $("#list4");
    $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(rowId)).addClass("edited");
    $grid.jqGrid("setCell", rowId, "area", "", "dirty-cell");
```